# Taxes in ubercart

Tags: 7, ubercart

I'm trying to charge cali sales tax in my ubercart store. I have taxes turned on, and have it set up with

"and: California Sales Tax conditions"

Taxes don't show up at any point in the checkout process.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know what the California Sales Tax conditions was. I think it might be some kind of stub for generating a custom condition somehow. Anyway, what I ended up doing was using the custom PHP code condition and calling this from it:

```
function check_california_tax($order) {
    $state = uc_get_zone_code($order->delivery_zone);
    if ($state == 'CA') {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

California Sales Tax has three elements. A state tax, a county tax and a district tax.

There are products that are exempt of all three taxes, like digital downloaded goods. State and County sales tax are always charged for a taxable good shipped in the state. The district tax is based on the shipping address of the goods.

There are over 400 district taxes, and multiple taxes can apply to a single address. Being districts, like a school catchment area for a school tax, or a hospital service area fro a hospital tax, the boundaries are not based on zip codes.

Further it is important that the correct districts and amounts are recorded for reporting the tax when paid over. In addition to correct reporting being a requirement of the business license, the districts get 50% of the monies for these taxes (50% to the state) and depend on them being correctly paid over to fund the costs of the local services.

It is not possible to do this using rules, one does need a table of districts, rates and how to determine what districts an address is in. The best way I have found is to use a commercial service from Avalara, Inc. The costs to them are a fraction of the development costs, let alone costs of maintaining the rates table, and eliminate audit issues later in the life of the business.

Google "ubercart avatax" - the results will be obvious.